# Behavior of ObservableCollection is different on UWP and WASM

Tags: uwp, webassembly, uno-platform

I have a uno app where the observableCollection behaves differently on UWP and WASM platforms.

It occurs in a GridView with an ItemsWrapGrid specifed as the itemsPanel. The  ItemSource is an ObservableCollection.  This is the xaml:

```
<GridView x:Name="gView" ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures,Mode=OneWay}" SelectionMode="Extended" IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="False" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="ImageSelectionChanged" >
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <not_wasm:ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"  MaximumRowsOrColumns="8"/>
            <wasm:WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="4">
                <Image Source="{Binding URL}" Width="{Binding Parent.ImageWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="200"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PictureKey}" Foreground="Yellow" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

The user is allows to select items and remove them from the view.  This is the relevant code:

```
if (result == 1)
{
    int ndx = vm.EvtViewModel.Pictures.IndexOf(pict);
    vm.EvtViewModel.Pictures.Remove(pict);
    if (ndx < vm.EvtViewModel.Pictures.Count)
    {
        vm.EvtViewModel.SelectedPicture = vm.EvtViewModel.Pictures[ndx];
    }
    else
    {
        vm.EvtViewModel.SelectedPicture = vm.EvtViewModel.Pictures.Count > 0 ? vm.EvtViewModel.Pictures.Last() : null;
    }
}
```

where vm.EvtViewModel.Pictures is the ObservableCollection.  The issue is that on UWP the items are removed and the remaining items below them are moved up the list.  On WASM, it triggers a complete redraw of the Grid.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy fix for this, but it'll be partially addressed in an upcoming Uno version. To understand the issue, note that you're using `WrapPanel` on WebAssembly and `ItemsWrapGrid` on UWP, which is the recommended approach since `ItemsWrapGrid` [isn't yet implemented for WASM](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/468).

`WrapPanel` is a 'non-virtualizing' panel, meaning it eagerly creates views for all items in the items source. At present, non-virtualizing panels are not optimized for use with `ObservableCollection` on WASM. This will be addressed by [this change](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/7256), which will prevent the entire grid being redrawn when a single item is inserted.